# Dynamic background-image

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, background-image

I want to have multiple `div` with different background URLs.
My inline razor for this code seems to be wrong:

```
<table>
@foreach (var item in fa.get_albums()) {
<tr>
    <td>
        <div style="background-image:url('@item.picture');">
            ///something
        </div>        
    </td>          
</tr>
}
</table>
```

What's the right way to put inline razor in to `background-imag:url()`?

Comment: In what way is this not working for you?

Comment: dear @DavidG thank you for helping. visual studio drew a green line under the code

Comment: seems like it is a wrong way to do this

Comment: Have you tried running it?

Comment: @DavidG yes nothing show up . if i delete the (@item.picture) the css property of background-image turns to blue otherwise it's just plain text

Comment: What is the URL contained in `item.picture`? Are you sure it's just not finding it due to the path to the image being incorrect?

Comment: no it's correct .<img src="~/content/@item.picture" > works fine .but  <div style="background-image:url('~/content/@item.picture');">  not working

Comment: @DavidG because of this i thought my way of using razor for background-URL is wrong

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue you have is that MVC will happily fix the relative paths inside an `img src` attribute but not for `style`. You should map that virtual path using `Url.Content()`:

```
<div style="background-image:url('@Url.Content(item.picture)');">
```